# Hide or remove column from sales order grid

Tags: magento2, layout, sales-order, layout-update, order-grid

I want to hide or remove **Purchase Point** column from sales order grid in backend using custom module, how do i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the layout for sales order grid, in order to do this create the sales order grid layout file inside your custom module

> Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

To hide element in this grid you have to set `componentDisabled` item argument to **true** , you'll also need to disable purchase point filter if you want to hide purchase point column. So the **sales_order_grid.xml** will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
              <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                  </item>
              </argument>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It only shifts colums.

Answer (score 2):

The solution should be

```
<column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Based on the vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:121

Comment: Thanks!!!  This worked like a charm.  Make sure you put it in an `adminhtml` directory... I stupidly wasn't and that tripped me up at first... __facepalm__

```app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml```

Comment: You are welcome ^^