# Remove column from Order grid based on condition

Tags: magento2, grid, column

I want to remove `status` column from Magento admin panel order grid.

I use below code to remove the `status` column in my `sales_order_grid.xml` file. [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222905/2443)

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

It removes `status` column successfully but I want to remove it based on a condition, value of a configuration field from `Stores > Configuration` section.

Is there any way I can add a condition on `componentDisabled`, or any other way to achieve my requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It Might be helpful to you.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="websites" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Websites" sortOrder="100">
            <settings>
                <addField>true</addField>
                <options class="Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Collection"/>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Websites</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Websites.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Websites extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Column name
     */
    const NAME = 'websites';

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @deprecated 101.0.0
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $websiteNames = [];
        foreach ($this->getData('options') as $website) {
            $websiteNames[$website->getWebsiteId()] = $website->getName();
        }
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $websites = [];
                foreach ($item[$fieldName] as $websiteId) {
                    if (!isset($websiteNames[$websiteId])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $websites[] = $websiteNames[$websiteId];
                }
                $item[$fieldName] = implode(', ', $websites);
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare component configuration
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        if ($this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's defualt Magento which is used for to display website based on condition.

Comment: Thanks Dharmendra for the answer. I will try to implement it with my code.

Comment: Welcome bro anytime.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav Can we able to hide column bases on admin logged in USER? I want to hide some column from admin grid using UI Component. Want to show some column for some user and rest of the user can able to see all columns

Comment: @Kartik we need to check for that. because i haven't check that before. But yes we can do that. Not impossible

Comment: @DharmendraJadav can you please post here so will be helping to me as well others. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav, I am displaying shipping amount for each order, in that the value is showing for each sku item in the order, how can we show the shipping amount for the last item, by keeping remaining as empty?

Comment: @jafar could you please more elaborate on this? I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav, the one i shared in skype is my new question

Comment: @jafar share link here

Comment: @DharmendraJadav, sharing link in other question is blocked for me, please you can check the link skype.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav, how can we remove column based on custom module is enabled/disabled configuration value?